$(Px,x)=\|Px\|^2$ implies that $P$ is a projection.
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $P$ is a bounded linear operator over it. If
$$
(Px,x)=\|Px\|^2,\quad \forall x\in H,
$$
I want to show $P$ is a projection.
If $H$ is a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$, I know how to prove it. Note that
$$
(Px,(I-P)x)=0,\quad\forall x\in H.
$$
For any $x,y\in H$, we have
$$
(P(x+y),(I-P)(x+y))=0.
$$
Using $(Px,(I-P)x)=(Py,(I-P)y)=0$ we can get
$$
(Px,(I-P)y)+(Py,(I-P)x)=0.
$$
Substitute $x$ by $\mathrm{i}x$ and we can get
$$
(Px,(I-P)y)-(Py,(I-P)x)=0
$$
and
$$
(Px,(I-P)y)=0,\quad\forall x,y\in H.
$$
Thus, $P$ is a projection.
But for $H$ over $\mathbb{R}$, I have no idea. If the symmetry of $P$ could be proven, then
$$
(Px,(I-P)y)=((I-P)x,Py)=(Py,(I-P)x)
$$
and $P$ is a projection.
Any help is welcome!

This is not true. On $\mathbb{R}^2$, the matrix,
$$P = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}$$
satisfies the required conditions, but is not even symmetric.

Since this matrix may be a bit mysterious, here is the process that led to it. Let $R$ be the rotation by $90^\circ$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. We want to find $P$ of the form $\alpha I + \beta R$, $\alpha, \beta > 0$. Then,
$$\alpha \|x\|^2 = (Px, x) = \|Px\|^2 = \alpha^2 \|x\|^2 + \beta^2 \|x\|^2$$
So $\alpha = \alpha^2 + \beta^2$. One solution to this is $\alpha = \beta = \frac{1}{2}$, which yields the matrix $P$ in the answer.

Thanks! I met this problem with the field $\mathbb{C}$, but I want to verify it over $\mathbb{R}$. Your counterexample is immediate.
